# eclipse: after signing with proguard, apk crashes

Tags: android, eclipse, proguard

I use eclipse. I am trying to publish app in play store.
without pro guard, apk works fine. 
with pro guard, i have added below options to keep Google, Facebook packages.

```
-keep class com.facebook.** {*;}
-keep class com.google.** {*;}
-keep class com.android.** {*;}
```

when i run signed apk in device, how could i debug it? or where could i see error or stack trace?
I tried everything but no clues so far?

How could i get error in logcat in eclipse when apk gets run on device?

Comment: I have the same problem - primarily, how to run a signed apk on a device via Eclipse so the LogCat output can be viewed.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this option to make the stacktraces a little more obvious but still obfuscated:

-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable,Signature

---

Alternatively you should de-obfuscate your stacktrace using the `mapping.txt` file that is generated when you create your proguarded build. This file is the "key" to changing your code back to normal. It is different every time you build a new apk so ensure you keep the correct file with the correct version.

Use `retrace` to de-obfuscate your stacktrace. (Get the crash stacktrace from your LogCat and save it to a file like `obfuscated_stacktrace.txt`.) Then run this command:

```
 retrace.bat -verbose mapping.txt obfuscated_stacktrace.txt
```

More details here [Proguard Decoding](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html#decoding)

Comment: I am asking different question. how to get "obfuscated_stacktrace.txt" ? I know, how to use retrace but how to get stack trace error, when apk runs on device?

Comment: @SanjayGupta if an apk runs on a device and crashes, it will still print this crash to the LogCat of the device